# Issue with Routing on Angular using AWS Amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction for this issue I'm experiencing deploying my Angular application to AWS Amplify.

It works and routes correctly on localhost, but not when deployed to AWS.

I've got my build up and running ok on both a master branch and a development branch, all with custom URL/SSL set up. So that is working brilliantly.

My issue is when I try to navigate to a URL on my application, I just get the index.html page being served.

I've read a few different articles here on Stack Overflow with similar issues, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've seen the mention of changing the redirect setting to a 200 redirect to index.html like the suggestions:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

But that still doesn't serve my pages, and just returns the contents of the index.html page (although the URL itself in the browser is showing the correct one like myurl.com/users/list).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you get 404 error, always redirect to serve index.html file to give a chance to Angular to handle the route.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting a 404 though, that's the issue. It's just using index.html instead of the page content it should be serving

Comment: Then it sounds like you just might not be importing your router module. But then again, you say your content is rendered for each route. If not a 404 and the index.html page is what's served as the response everytime for each route, that's what you want. Are you expecting /users/list to arrive in your Network tab with the content from your UserListComponent? That would be server-side rendered pages.